# Moving images in python tkinter canvas

Tags: python, image, object, tkinter, canvas

#I am having trouble moving the images in my tkinter canvas and binding it

```
self.image1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="player2.png")  # Use self.image
player2 = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = self.image1, anchor = tk.NW)
```

#I have created the def statement for right, left, up and down which is not letting me post and the root.bind to my tkinter

Comment: Use `image_id = <tkinter.Canvas>.create_image(...)` and then `<tkinter.Canvas>.move(image_id, change_in_x, change_in_y)`

Comment: I don't see any code showing any attempt at moving the image. Please [edit]  your question to include a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possible reasons your code isn't working.
The first may be the focus is not on the canvas.

```py
canvas.focus_set()
```

The second may have to do with your bindings.

```py
image1 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='player2.png', master=canvas)
player2 = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=image1, anchor='nw')
a = canvas.event_add('<<CHOOSE>>', '<Key-Left>', '<Key-Right>', '<Key-Up>', '<Key-Down>')
b = canvas.bind('<<CHOOSE>>', statement)
canvas.focus_set()
```